# How do I get apache 2 to serve up home directory?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, rewrite, home-directory

I have a domain name I have registered and it is currently showing the Apache 2 Test Page from the /var/www/html/ directory, I was wondering how I can get it to point to a home directory instead ie: home/user/public_html/?  Do I have to use the rewrite engine?  All help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: As a site for [*professionals*](http://serverfault.com/faq) we expect that you have invested some time in reading the [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/) (or at least a tutorial, which you can find on Google). Your question is answered in the Apache documentation. If after reading the documentation there is something you do not understand feel free to ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to edit the DocumentRoot directive in Apache or setup a new Vhost.